# Gradle build fails on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, azure-devops

Recently, I have a build problem for Android Studio project (without tests) on Visual Studio Team Services with default Android build I defined. When it come to the Gradle build, I get `Error: d:\a\1\s\gradlew.bat failed with return code: 1`. Detailed error log shown in log is:

> 2017-09-25T11:17:42.7487259Z java.io.IOException: Failed to move away or delete existing target file: C:\java\androidsdk\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7487259Z Move it away manually and try again.
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7487259Z    at com.android.repository.io.FileOpUtils.safeRecursiveOverwrite(FileOpUtils.java:131)
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7497258Z    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doComplete(BasicInstaller.java:138)
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7497258Z    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.complete(AbstractPackageOperation.java:162)
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7497258Z    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installRemotePackages(DefaultSdkLoader.java:347)
>   ...
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7547263Z "Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)" complete.
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7547263Z "Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)" failed.
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7677265Z 
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7687266Z FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7687266Z 
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7687266Z * What went wrong:
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7687266Z A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7687266Z > Failed to install the following SDK components:
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7687266Z   [Android Support Repository]
>   2017-09-25T11:17:42.7687266Z   Please install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. Does the build process have write access in the android-sdk tree?

Comment: @Henry How to check this ?

Comment: I tried to fix this by using the info here: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3971), however, I now get this error: 

> File C:\Users\buildguest\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+ as no versions of com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout are available.

Comment: Do you use Hosted 2017 build agent or private build agent? If you are using private build agent, do you install Android Support Repository 47 on build agent machine? (Check in SDK manager or run `[android sdk path]\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --list commmand`)

Comment: @starain-MSFT I'm using  Hosted VS2017 build agent.

Comment: Could you share a sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Well it is not sample project, it is a real project. It works and build fine locally. Do you need some file to look at ?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Here is a screenshot from build: https://imgur.com/a/AVEjU

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue with a new project?

Comment: @starain-MSFT I created new repo and new empty project and it works/build fine. Obviously is the problem with the line: "Could not find any matches for the com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+" as no versions  of  com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout are available.